# gridview edittemplate not showing content

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have grid view with three column name, rate, category

I am also using ajax rate here and one dropdown within edittemplate which binded with sqldatasource.

But when click on edit it is not showing the drop down.

Please help to sort out this problem.

Code is

```
<asp:gridview id="GVTweet" runat="server" allowpaging="True" allowsorting="True"
    autogeneratecolumns="False" gridlines="None" pagesize="15" width="700px" onselectedindexchanged="GVTweet_SelectedIndexChanged"
    onrowcancelingedit="GVTweet_RowCancelingEdit" onrowediting="GVTweet_RowEditing"
    onrowupdated="GVTweet_RowUpdated" onrowupdating="GVTweet_RowUpdating">
        <HeaderStyle />
        <AlternatingRowStyle Height="70px" />
        <RowStyle Height="70px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="~/images/twet1.png" HeaderText="Tweets" 
            ItemStyle-Height="70px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="auto">
                    <tr style="width:400px;">
                        <td align="left" style="height:70px;" valign="top">
                        <span class="box_imag">
                        <asp:Image ID="ScreenImage0" runat="server" height="50" 
                            ImageUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageUrl")%>' width="50" />
                        </span><span class="box_cont">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id")%>' Visible="false">
                        </asp:Label>
                        <div>
                        <strong>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                                onclick='setscreenname(&#039;<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ScreenName")%>&#039;)' 
                                rel="external">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblScreenName0" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ScreenName")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </a>
                        </strong>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblText0" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="meta">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDate0" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="~/images/rate1.png" 
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerCss1" HeaderText="Rate(1-5)" 
                SortExpression="Rating" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="auto">
                    <tr style="width:150px;" valign="top" >
                        <td style="height:70px;">
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpnlTweet0" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <cc1:Rating ID="rateTweet" runat="server" CurrentRating='<%# Bind("Rating") %>' 
                                        EmptyStarCssClass="empatyStarRating" FilledStarCssClass="filledStarRating" 
                                        MaxRating="5" onchanged="rateTweet_Changed" StarCssClass="ratingStar" 
                                        WaitingStarCssClass="savedStarRating">
                                    </cc1:Rating>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="~/images/category1.png" 
                    HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerCss2" HeaderStyle-Width="148px" 
                    HeaderText="Categorize It" ItemStyle-CssClass="iteamHeader2">                                           
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table width="auto" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr align="center" valign="top" style="width:150px;" >
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="height:70px; float:left;" >                            
                            <asp:Label ID="lblid1" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"CategoryName")%>' ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>                                        
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldivcategory" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="dropdowntweet" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="CategoryName" DataValueField="CategoryId" >
                                </asp:DropDownList>                   
           </EditItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>                                    
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this and change datasource is solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the DataKeyNames property on the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVTweet" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PrimaryKeyName"...
```

Comment: ya i have tried this but it didnt work please give me another idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    protected void GVTweet_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
            GVTweet.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            //Load Grid
    }

<asp:gridview id="GVTweet" runat="server" allowpaging="True" allowsorting="True"
autogeneratecolumns="False" gridlines="None" pagesize="15" width="700px"     onselectedindexchanged="GVTweet_SelectedIndexChanged"
onrowcancelingedit="GVTweet_RowCancelingEdit" onrowediting="GVTweet_RowEditing"
onrowupdated="GVTweet_RowUpdated" onrowupdating="GVTweet_RowUpdating">
```